# how to see the file dowloaded by RNFetchBlob in IOS device

Tags: react-native

I used `react-native-fetch-blob` to download file excel from api. I can see it's downloading successfully but as you know On iOS platform the directory path will be changed every time you access to the file system.

I show the path by console.log:

`"/Users/admin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/749E7AAA-F568-4F56-9606-FF23E84946CF/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/95C3997D-BBB3-4FB3-94C4-ADB0331940B2/Bus_Booking.app/MYFILE.xlsx"`.

But when I go to the folder of the device, there are no files to see.
How can I download and write the path where a user can see their device?

Comment: You can download file to storage and then view it. Like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65739315/9089919).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save file to a directory, else it will be saved in a temporary directory only available to app.

```
const baseDir = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DownloadDir;
const path = `${baseDir}/my-file.png`;
RNFetchBlob.fs.writeFile(path, <temp file path>, 'uri');
```

`react-native-fetch-blob` repo is not maintained anymore. Use `rn-fetch-blob`

Comment: plz tell me what is temp file path, sorry for the noob question

Comment: DocumentDir
CacheDir
MainBundleDir (Can be used to access files embedded on iOS apps only)
DCIMDir (Android Only)
DownloadDir (Android Only)
MusicDir (Android Only)
PictureDir (Android Only)
MovieDir (Android Only)
RingtoneDir (Android Only)
SDCardDir (0.9.5+ Android Only)

Comment: i want to save to iphone or ipad not android device

Comment: @HồQuốcHuy the path you mentioned in your question is the tmp path `/Users/admin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/749E7AAA-F568-4F56-9606-FF23E84946CF/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/95C3997D-BBB3-4FB3-94C4-ADB0331940B2/Bus_Booking.app/MYFILE.xlsx`

Comment: the path you write is a dynamic path. So i used react native FileViewer to open file and user can save it to their device.